# Ошибка вычисления float значений корней кубического уравнения ax^3+bx^2+cx+d на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как на python реализовать программу, вычисляющую корни кубического уравнения ax^3+bx^2+cx+d? Пробовала через формулу Кардано, но столкнулась с ошибкой вычисления чисел float. Такой же код на с++ работает, на python нет( ПОМОГИТЕ.

```
import cmath
        
print('Решим уравнение вида a*x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d=0')
a = input('Введите значение a: ')
b = input('Введите значение b: ')
c = input('Введите значение c: ')
d = input('Введите значение d: ')
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
d = float(c)  # <-   ВОТ ОШИБКА))))))
        
if a == 0 and b == 0 and c == 0 and d == 0:
    print('Ошибка')
    exit()
p = (3 * a * c - b ** 2) / (3 * a ** 2)
q = (2 * b ** 3 - 9 * a * b * c + 27 * a ** 2 * d) / (27 * a ** 3)
Q = (p / 3) ** 3 + (q / 2) ** 2
print('p = ', p, '\nq = ', q, '\nQ = ', Q)
if q == 0:
    F = cmath.pi/2
if q < 0:
    F = cmath.atan(-2 * cmath.sqrt(-Q) / q)
if q > 0:
    F = cmath.atan(-2 * cmath.sqrt(-Q) / q) + cmath.pi
        
if Q < 0:
    x1 = 2 * (-p / 3)**0.5 * cmath.cos(F / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    x1 = round(x1.real, 5) 
    x2 = 2 * (-p / 3)**0.5 * cmath.cos((F / 3) + 2 * cmath.pi / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    x2 = round(x2.real, 5)
    x3 = 2 * (-p / 3)**0.5 * cmath.cos((F / 3) + 4 * cmath.pi / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    x3 = round(x3.real, 5) 
    print('\nx1 =', x1, '\nx2 =', x2, '\nx3 =', x3)
elif Q == 0:
    x1 = 2 * (-q / 2) ** (1 / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    x2 = (-q / 2) ** (-1 / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    x3 = (-q / 2) ** (-1 / 3) - b / (3 * a)
    print('\nx1 =', x1, '\nx2 =', x2, '\nx3 =', x3)
elif Q > 0:
    alfa = (-q / 2 + Q ** 0.5) ** (1 / 3)
    beta = -abs((-q / 2 - Q ** 0.5) ** (1 / 3))
    y1 = alfa + beta
    y2 = complex(-((alfa + beta) / 2), (alfa - beta) / 2 * 3 ** 0.5)
    y3 = complex(-((alfa + beta) / 2), -(alfa - beta) / 2 * 3 ** 0.5)
    x1 = y1 - b / (3 * a)
    x1 = round(x1, 5)
    x2 = y2 - b / (3 * a)
    x2 = round(x2.real, 5) + round(x2.imag, 5) * 1j
    x3 = y3 - b / (3 * a)
    x3 = round(x3.real, 5) + round(x3.imag, 5) * 1j
    print('\nalfa =', alfa, '\nbeta =', beta, '\n\nx1 =', x1, '\nx2 =', x2, '\nx3 =', x3)
```

при вводе например 1 2 3 4 выдает:

```
p =  1.6666666666666667 
q =  1.5925925925925926 
Q =  0.8055555555555556

alfa = 0.46605598306870266 
beta = -1.1920360981046767 

x1 = -1.39265 
x2 = (-0.30368+1.43595j) 
x3 = (-0.30368-1.43595j)
```

правильный ответ:

```
x1 = -1.6506291914393746                                                                                        
x2 = -0.1746854042803145 + 1.546868887231393*i                                                                                       
x3 = -0.1746854042803145 - 1.546868887231393*i
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос через [edit] вашу попытку сделать на питоне, так будет проще помочь :)

Comment: и текст ошибки целиком скопируйте в свой вопрос

Comment: @Tanya По-моему надо просто округлить результаты до вменяемой точности. Например так: `x2 = round(x2.real, 5) + round(x2.imag, 5) * 1j`. Ибо `float` - штука вообще не точная в плане репрезентации чисел.

Comment: пожалуйста, если правите код, то дополняйте вопрос там а не в комментариях

Comment: @GrAnd новая проблема: ввожу 1 2 3 4, вместо: `x1=-1.6506291914393746`
`x2=-0.1746854042803145+ i*1.546868887231393`
`x3=0.1746854042803089- i*1.5468688872313884` получаю ответ:  `x1=-1.39265 ` 
`x2 =(-0.30368+1.43595j)` 
`x3 = (-0.30368-1.43595j)` 
код исправила

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас формулы для альфы и беты идентичные и, по-моему, неправильные.

Comment: я исправила формулы, сейчас как в википедии, но ответ все равно неправильный (добавила актуальный). Ошибка идет аж из вычисления beta. 
Я предполагаю, что python неправильно считает, но не знаю как решить эту проблемку

Comment: добавила в  beta модуль: `beta = -abs((-q / 2 - Q ** 0.5) ** (1 / 3))` ,  получила верный ответ для 1 2 2 2 , но при вводе одинаковых значений, к примеру: 1 1 1 1,    комплексные корни выдает неправильные 
`x1 = -1.0 `

`x2 = (5.551115123125783e-17+0.9999999999999999j) `

`x3 = (5.551115123125783e-17-0.9999999999999999j)`

Comment: @Tanya По-моему надо просто округлить до вменяемой точности. Например так: `x2 = round(x2.real, 5) + round(x2.imag, 5) * 1j`. Ибо `float` - штука вообще не точная в плане репрезентации чисел.

Comment: @GrAnd ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!

Comment: @Tanya, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

код абсолютно правильный, 
но в 11 строке:

```
d=float(c)
```

вместо

```
d=float(d)
```

В этом и ошибка